# git pull origin branch wants a merge on clean current master branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge-conflict

I'm on a my master branch which is a perfect clean (but git presents it that it is ahead of origin/master by 14 commits). When I try to pull a different branch from origin (Eagle) git wants me to merge a few files.

This is not what I expect: When pulling a branch it should import the remote branch and leave the current HEAD untouched and not bother me with merge conflicts. In my perception The 2 branches live apart but peacefully from eachother, without any conflicts. But this perception holds no longer.

What causes these conflicts and how to restore 2 different branches without merging?

Below a transcript of the git session on commandline.

```
HEAD is now at 34e47ab ISS-652 misspelled MockBean in test/ApplicationContext
build@jenkins/p-project/workspace> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 14 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
build@jenkins/p-project/workspace> git log -5
.. Same as origin
build@jenkins/p-project/workspace> git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
build@jenkins/p-project/workspace> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 14 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
build@jenkins/p-project/workspace> git pull origin Eagle
From ssh://git@stash.europe.intranet:7999/hig/p-project-container
 * branch            Eagle     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merged pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-client/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-client/pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-conf/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-conf/pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-conf/src/main/resources/dpl/P-Project_Container.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-conf/src/main/resources/dpl/P-Project_Container.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-conf/src/main/resources/was/P-Project_Container-app-env.cfg
Auto-merged p-project-container-ear/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-ear/pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-filters/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-filters/pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-ldap/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-ldap/pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-tomcattest/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-tomcattest/pom.xml
Auto-merged p-project-container-web/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in p-project-container-web/pom.xml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
build@jenkins/p-project/workspace>
```

Comment: Nothing you've shown us here strikes me as being necessarily wrong or inexplicable.  Why would you think that doing a `git pull` would _not_ potentially cause merge conflicts?

Comment: If you have 2 branches locally you should maybe move the head to the branch you want to pull. Git checkout Eagle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `git pull origin branch` does is that it fetches and merges the remote branch into your current local branch. So, the result of the above command is - to merge the remote branch `eagle` into your local master.

I guess what you want is to create a new local independent branch which tracks the corresponding remote branch. You can do that with

```
git fetch
git checkout -b eagle --track origin/eagle
```

This will create a new separate local branch `eagle` which would reflect the remote branch `eagle`.

This local branch will be independent of your local master branch and keep your local master untouched.

You can do `git status` and it will show `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/eagle'.` and you can checkout master with `git checkout master` and then doing a `git status` will show `ahead by 14 commits`.

Answer (score 1):

I will provide an explanation of what you did, after which point it will be clear that the results you got can be expected.

You made 14 commits to the `master` branch since the point when you last synched up with the remote repository:

```
git commit -m 'You did something'   # you did this 14 times
```

Next you pushed your work to the remote:

```
git push origin master
```

Note carefully that `git status` is still showing your local branch as being 14 commits ahead of `master`.  Your local branch is ahead of the old stale local tracking branch, but is completely in sync with the remote `master`.

Next, you did this:

```
git pull origin Eagle
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/Eagle
```

In other words, you first fetched the latest changes from the remote into all your tracking branches (good), then you merged the `Eagle` branch into your local `master` (bad).  The reason this happened is because you never switched branches before doing this `git pull`.

**What you need to do to fix this:**

You need to take 2 steps.  First, you need to undo the incorrect merge into the `master` branch.  Second, you should switch branches to `Eagle`, and then do the `git pull`.

```
# on the master branch
git log
# find the SHA-1 hash immediately BEFORE the bad merge, then do
git reset --hard SHA-1
# next switch to the Eagle branch
git checkout Eagle
# finally do the correct pull
git pull origin Eagle
```

You may still have merge conflicts, but they will be the real conflicts and not the result of merging `Eagle` into `master`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and very understandable answer! I was under the assumption that doing `git pull origin Eagle` effectively creates a new local branch Eagle, but this is obviously not the case. I see where I went wrong and even feel a bit embarrassed about it.

Comment: I didn't even think you were trying to create a new local branch.  I thought that, for whatever reason, you were trying to just switch branches and update `Eagle`.  Actually, the other answer given is correct for creating a new branch from your up to date `master`.

Comment: Yeah I was too fast with commenting and rewarding (hadn't even seen the other answer). Hope you don't mind awarding the other answer.

Comment: Just make sure you follow my steps to undo the bad merge _before_ you try to create a new branch.  You had a bad merge commit in your `master` and it needs to be removed.